# jQuery selector question

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have a unordered list like the one below:

```
<ul id="tabs">
      <li><a href="#tab1">latest news</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab2">latest posts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">latest posts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4">latest posts</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can't find a jQuery selector that gets the next list item from the one whith the .active class, so if .active is the second one the jQuery selector will give me the third list item.

Thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one step: jQuery('li.active + li');

See [adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: +1 This answer is preferred, since it only requires one query from the selector engine.

Comment: Thank's. Yes you are right, but how do I select the previous list item using this method?

Comment: You can't. CSS is short on selectors that select an element based on content that follows the element's start tag.

Comment: you'll have use `prev()` I think.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul#tabs li.active').next();
```

Comment: Thank's alot I thought this will select only the next list items that have a class .active.